# What is the difference between executing query statements using 'execute' and directy in PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, procedure

```
st :='SELECT USERNAME FROM LOGIN WHERE USERNAME =: a and PASSWORD =: b';
execute immediate st into un using username,pw;
```

Or

```
SELECT USERNAME INTO un FROM LOGIN WHERE USERNAME = username and PASSWORD = pw;
```

where `username`, `un` and `pw` are `varchar2(50)` variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every `PL/SQL` will be first compiled before execution. Compilation here involves, both syntax checks of PL/SQL constructs and semantic checks over the SQLs being used.

Running SQLs via [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm) means, the query is parsed and executed dynamically. And then we name it *Dynamic* SQL.The dynamic SQLs are formed using a string, and the query , hence is not known to Oracle before hand. And only during runtime, it is compiled and executed.

Whereas, in the other method, the `SQL` is parsed for semantic checks during compilation itself. We call it as *Static* SQL. We get,all the invalid SQL statement errors during compilation itself.

The other main difference, would be, when a Static SQL is been used in a `PROCEDURE` or `FUNCTION`. Oracle would create a dependency of that table name with the `Procedure`/`function`. You can find them in the [dba_dependencies](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1041.htm#i1576452) table.

It is very important to create such dependencies because, when the table is being altered with modifying the column name that is referred in a function or the table/view/type itself is dropped, Then Oracle would `INVALIDATE` the function. Thus making sure, we dont get unexpected Exceptions.But DYNAMIC sqls would be completely anonymous and have no dependencies created. You may get a `ORA-942 TABLE OR VIEW DOESNOT EXISTS` error, only with DYNAMIC sql and not  with a Static SQL, just because of this reason.

The below query would list out all the table names referred in the procedure or function, either as a Synonym(table referred cross schemas, without schema name) and tablename directly with schema name(or default schema)

```
select 
   proc_syn.referenced_owner, 
   proc_syn.referenced_name, 
   proc_syn.referenced_type,
   syn_tab.table_name
from 
   dba_dependencies proc_syn, dba_synonyms syn_tab, dba_tables tables
where 
     proc_syn.name= 'YOUR_PROC' 
  AND REFERENCED_TYPE in ( 'SYNONYM','TABLE')
  AND proc_syn.referenced_name = syn_tab.synonym_name
  AND syn_tab.synonym_name = tables.table_name
  AND syn_tab.owner = 'PUBLIC'
order by 
  proc_syn.referenced_owner, syn_tab.table_name;
```

Comment: Well said about dba_dependencies also. Thanks @Maheswaran Ravisankar

Answer (score 1):

**Execute immediate** is used to invoke dynamic SQL for more information see [oracle Documents](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/11_dynam.htm)

Comment: Accepted answer!! Hmm :)

Comment: :) @oracleuser I m delighted

Comment: :) I understand that.. Cheers dude!